# Dijkstra algorithm C++ Incorrect output

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

My previous question was answered, but i'm wondering how could i alter this to show the intersections that the lowest route has passed through? Thanks

Note: driverMap is a 2D 14x14 integer vector that holds the distances it takes to get to each vertex

```
void startFirst(vector< vector<int> > driverMap, vector<Car> allCars, int congestFactor)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    int Intersections[driverMap.size()];
    int Distances[driverMap.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < driverMap.size(); i++)
    {
        Intersections[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < driverMap.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Intersection '" << i << "': "; 
        for(int k = 0; k < driverMap.size(); k++)
        {
            cout << driverMap[i][k] << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        int startInt = allCars[i].getStart();
        Intersections[startInt] = -1;
        Distances[startInt] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < driverMap.size(); i++) 
        {
            if(i != startInt)
            {
                Distances[i] = driverMap[startInt][i];
            }
        }

        cout << "FOR INTERSECTION: '" << startInt << "'" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        for (int l = 0; l < driverMap.size(); l++) 
        {
            if(l != startInt)
            {
                Dijkstra(driverMap, Intersections, Distances);
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < driverMap.size(); k++) 
        {
            cout << Distances[k] << "|";
        }
    }
    cout << "Total time simulated: " << (clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
}

void Dijkstra(vector< vector<int> > driverMap, int Intersections[], int Distances[]) 
{
    int minValue = 9999;
    int minNode = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < driverMap.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (Intersections[i] == -1) 
        { 
            continue; 
        }

        if (Distances[i] > 0 && Distances[i] < minValue) 
        {
            minValue = Distances[i];
            minNode = i;
        }
    }

    Intersections[minNode] = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < driverMap.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (driverMap[minNode][i] < 0) 
        { 
            continue; 
        }

        if (Distances[i] < 0) 
        {
            Distances[i] = minValue + driverMap[minNode][i];
            continue;
        }

        if ((Distances[minNode] + driverMap[minNode][i]) < Distances[i]) 
        {
            Distances[i] = minValue + driverMap[minNode][i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is : Incorrect assumption. **Your assumption is incorrect since there is no direct access from 5 to 4.**

What you claim is you can get to 0 from 5 is path `5-4-0` with distance `4800` (2600 + 2200).
However, the fact is you can only get path `5-8-4-0` by your code with distance `5200` (1500 + 1500 + 2200).

Please be aware that distance `2600` in Intersection 5 is for Intersection 3, not Intersection 4. You are starting with index 0, not 1.

Comment: Oh my god, so what I've done is correct just a deskchecking error?

Comment: @JacksonCollins The only concern to your code is `int minValue = 9999;    int minNode = 0;`. A better way for this part is to initiate a sufficient large value for minValue and non-exist node for minNode, say -1.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help, but what would be a sufficient large value?

Comment: @JacksonCollins A sufficient large value usually denote Integer.MAX_VALUE (for java, not sure for C++) which is the maximum value allowed for the data type. You can also use a value that will always greater than any Distances[i] for any possible input. It helps to prevent potential error when requirement change like facing cases `Distance[i] >= 10000`.

Comment: Hey would you know how I could alter this to save the lowest distance route and the intersections it goes through?

Comment: @JacksonCollins Not sure if this work. If I am not wrong, Dijkstra algorithm is able to do back-tracking. You can make a new int array path[driverMap.size()] to keep track where the min Value of the node comes from. I mean update the path[i] with minNode in the last two if-loop when you update Distance[i]. Also, initiate all path[i] with startint except startint==i. If this work, you should be able to turn this into a path instead of a backward point by turning int array to string array with slightly change of update value.

Comment: @JacksonCollins BTW, you could post this as another question so that everybody can share their idea, not just my idea ;)

Answer (score 3):

Manual drawing of the graph below backs up the @hk6279's answer.
Optimal path to "0" cannot be achieved when arriving from "13".
It should either be from "1" or "4" to "0" and as @hk6279 noted and the program correctly computed, the optimal path is "5"-"8"-"4"-"0" of distance 5200.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice drawing. Please help to edit my name "hk6279", not "kh6219" in your post.

Comment: Nice drawing, thank you. I miscalculated my anticipated result

Answer (score -3):

Refer below for Dijkstra's algorithm in C:
http://www.c-program-example.com/2011/10/c-program-to-solve-dijkstras-algorithm.html

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't help my problem as I use c++ and I don't understand why my output is incorrect.